# Python And Random Forest Algorithm

Tags: python, random-forest

I'm trying to use Python's Random Forest ML (machine learning) algorithm with a *.csv file, and this is information is inside that *csv.file

```
DateTime;Status;Energy
28-02-2014 19:30:00;True;10,1
28-02-2011 06:15:00;False;15,6;
28-02-2011 06:30:00;False;15,2;
28-02-2011 06:45:00;False;15,6;
......
```

Which packages or library(random forest models) do I need to use for analysis with that information?

My code :

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from numpy import genfromtxt, savetxt
    def main():
        dataset = genfromtxt(open("C:\\Users\\PVanDro\\Desktop\\Ddata\\Building0.csv"), delimiter=';', dtype='f8')[1:]
        target = [x[0] for x in dataset]
        train = [x[1:] for x in dataset]
        rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100)
        rf.fit(train, target)
        savetxt("C:\\Users\\PVanDro\\Desktop\\Ddata\\Building0_0.csv", delimiter=';', fmt='%f')

    if __name__=='__main__':
         main()
```

But i had errors :

```
  File "C:/Users/PVanDro/Desktop/Folder for test/RandomForestExamples1/MainFile.py", line 17, in main
    rf.fit(train, target)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\forest.py", line 224, in fit
    X, = check_arrays(X, dtype=DTYPE, sparse_format="dense")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 283, in check_arrays
    _assert_all_finite(array)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 43, in _assert_all_finite
    " or a value too large for %r." % X.dtype)
ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float32').
```

How i can fix that errors ?

Comment: You might want to edit your question and add some code that you are tried.

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Comment: Mr. Concolato ! I still had that problem. Do you have any ideal how to solved it ?

Comment: According to your errors, the code seems to have an issue with something in your data that is not consistent with your dtype='f8'. Are you perhaps trying to parse a date value like it was a float?

Comment: Mr.Concolato ! I'm trying to parse a date value : "fName = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\PVanDro\\Desktop\\Ddata\\Building0.csv", index_col=False, decimal=',', sep=';', header=0)" But i cannot create graphic. Do you have any ideal or another packages or library i can use ?

Comment: Just updated my answer.

Comment: Mr. Concolato! Thanks,  i'll try and update my result for you as soon as i can.

Comment: Mr.Comcolato! The most important that i need libraries to create predicted data from *.csv file not libraries to visualize that data with graphics.

Comment: Just responding to your previous comment saying, "But i cannot create graphic". Did you get your predictive set?

Comment: Yes ! In some ways, not what i want but i think i can using that method for getting predictive. Thanks for helping me Mr.Concolato. Happy new year !

Answer (score 2):

This is a [great tutorial](https://www.kaggle.com/c/digit-recognizer/forums/t/2299/getting-started-python-sample-code-random-forest) that explains what you are looking for. Here is some sample code to try out.

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from numpy import genfromtxt, savetxt

def main():
    #create the training & test sets, skipping the header row with [1:]
    dataset = genfromtxt(open('Data/train.csv','r'), delimiter=',', dtype='f8')[1:]    
    target = [x[0] for x in dataset]
    train = [x[1:] for x in dataset]
    test = genfromtxt(open('Data/test.csv','r'), delimiter=',', dtype='f8')[1:]

    #create and train the random forest
    #multi-core CPUs can use: rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, n_jobs=2)
    rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100)
    rf.fit(train, target)

    savetxt('Data/submission2.csv', rf.predict(test), delimiter=',', fmt='%f')

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Once you have created your new, say predictive data set, you can use a multitude of libraries to visualize that data with graphics. Here are a few:

1. [Bokeh](http://bokeh.pydata.org/) - A Python based visualization library for web-based representations
2. [D3](http://d3js.org/) - Another web-base JavaScript library for visualizing data. [Here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887235) is one example you could use with CSV.
3. [Ploty](https://plot.ly/python/) - A Python based visualization

There are more, but You can interrogate Google for that. ;)

Comment: Thanks ! Mr. Concolato, but where i can have "train.csv" file ?

Comment: Just rename or place your data in your *csv file that you mentioned above into new "train.csv" and save it.